# CSS shrink on hover

Tags: html, css, menu, hover

I'm making a menu with `<ul>`/`<li>` and CSS.

Here's what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/gANfS/6/

The problem is that if you mouse over the top edge within the 5 pixel margin, it starts getting crazy and going back and forth between the hover and unhovered state because the size of the block grows and shrinks. How can I fix this? When I shrink the li, I don't want to be shrinking the hover area. That would fix it, but I'm not sure how to pull it off. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a hack job...but it will work

instead of `magin-top:5px;`

do `border-top:5px solid black;`

if you want your background to to be a different color, just make sure to set the border color to the same color.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `li` content into a div, then apply your shrinking to that div (`.sel div:hover` instead of `li:hover`) and this should make it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gANfS/15/ I tried that, it didn't fix it. I might be doing it wrong though?

Comment: Well, I may have had some luck at my try, as your implementation is close to mine. Anyway, PTBG's solution is a better one.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is on mouse over, the button moves down and sets a `margin-top 5px`. Then, if the mouse is over that top edge, the button no longer has "hover" state and it retracts back. When it does get back, it switches to mouse over state and the journey begins again.

You could use `padding-top:5px` instead of `margin-top` and set the HOVER effect on the whole container. Padding, as opposed to margin, is space inside the element. That way, when the mouse is over the top edge, it would still be considered as over the element and it will not flicker anymore.

Comment: If I use padding instead, then the box doesn't shrink. That's the look I'm aiming for.

Comment: Yes, to keep that effect you need to do some changes. One solution is to create a new container with the background and the text that should be moved down. The hover styles should still be applied to the whole li. Does it make sense?